# Trying to automate Tor to do something on a site and change identity each time. Need some guidance

Tags: html, http, curl, request, tor

I really need some help with automating Tor to do something on a site (in this case, check something on a poll) and then restart Tor with a new identity. I have never done anything remotely close to this. I only know HTML, CSS and JS fairly well.

Now, to sum up, I want to make a loop that repeatedly accesses a site on Tor, checks something on that site and then restarts Tor with a new identity.

If anyone could give me some guidance and tell me what I can use, it would be much appreciated. I have the time and patience to learn, so anything works really.

Comment: What language? Bash, Python, PHP, Perl, Go, ...Haskell?

Comment: Python has a pretty good Tor ecosystem and quite a few examples of what you're trying to do posted here in the [tor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tor) tag.  Good place to start looking and come up with a starting point for question with example code.

Comment: I wrote a [Tor library in PHP](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils) and you can combine these two examples ([CurlWrapper](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlWrapper.php) and [NewNym](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/tc_NewNym.php)) which together would scrape content over Tor and then change the IP.  I can also write up some Python examples for this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are examples using PHP and Python 3 to accomplish what you want.  They're simple starting points for making requests over Tor and changing your identity on demand.

The PHP example uses [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/torutils) to communicate with the controller and wrap cURL through Tor.

The Python example uses [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) to communicate with the controller and [Requests](http://python-requests.org/) for sending requests over Tor's SOCKS proxy.

The examples assume you have Tor working already and the `SocksPort` set to 9050, and the `ControlPort` set to 9051 with cookie authentication working, or a controller password of `password`.

## PHP

#### Set Up

- Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to install the TorUtils package (you can also download the zipball and extract)
- Once composer is working, run `composer require dapphp/torutils` from your project directory to download and install dependencies

#### Code

```
<?php

use Dapphp\TorUtils\ControlClient;
use Dapphp\TorUtils\TorCurlWrapper;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoloader
// include TorUtils/src/ControlClient.php and TorUtils/src/TorCurlWrapper.php if using without composer

$controller = new ControlClient; // get a new controller object

try {
    $controller->connect('127.0.0.1', 9051); // connect to Tor controller on localhost:9051
    $controller->authenticate('password');   // attempt to authenticate using "password" as password
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    die("Failed to open connection to Tor controller.  Reason: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
}   

// issue 10 requests, changing identity after each request
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    try {
        $curl = new TorCurlWrapper('127.0.0.1', 9050); // connect to Tor SOCKS proxy on localhost:9050
        $curl->httpGet('https://drew-phillips.com/ip-info/'); // issue request
        $body = strip_tags($curl->getResponseBody());

        if (preg_match('/Using Tor:\s*Yes/i', $body)) {
            echo "You appear to be using Tor successfully.  ";
        } else {
            echo "Proxy worked but this Tor IP is not known.  ";
        }

        if (preg_match('/IP Address:\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/i', $body, $ip)) {
            echo "Source IP = {$ip[1]}\n";
        } else {
            echo "Couldn't determine IP!\n";
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo "HTTP request failed!  " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

    // TODO: issue more requests as needed here

    echo "\n";
    sleep(10);

    try {
        // send signal to controller to request new identity (IP)
        $controller->signal(ControlClient::SIGNAL_NEWNYM);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo "Failed to issue NEWNYM signal: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

## Python 3

#### Set Up

This example uses Python 3 and assumes you have the Python interpreter up and running and have the following packages installed: `requests`, `requests[socks]`, `socks`, `urllib3`, `stem`.

On Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo -H pip3 install requests requests[socks] socks urllib3 stem`

#### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
from stem.control import Controller, Signal
import time
import sys
import re

# specify Tor's SOCKS proxy for http and https requests
proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
}

try:
    controller = Controller.from_port(9051) # try to connect to controller at localhost:9051
except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    controller.authenticate('password') # try to authenticate with password "password"
except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
    print("Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect")
    sys.exit(1)

# issue 10 requests, changing identity after each request
for i in range(1,10):
    # issue request, passing proxies to request
    r = requests.get('https://drew-phillips.com/ip-info/', proxies=proxies)

    #print(r.text)

    m = re.search('<dt>Using Tor:</dt><dd><span[^>]*>Yes', r.text)
    if m:
        print("You appear to be using Tor successfully.  ", end="")
    else:
        print("Proxy worked but this Tor IP is not known.  ", end="")

    m = re.search('<dt>IP Address:</dt><dd>(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)</dd>', r.text)
    if m:
        print("Source IP = %s" % m.groups(1))
    else:
        print("Failed to scrape IP from page")

    try:
        # send signal to controller to request new identity (IP)
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("NEWNYM failed: %s" % ex)

    time.sleep(10)
```