# Send HTTP request via TOR while changing the IP

Tags: python, http-post, tor, socks

I'm in need of some help.

I want to make a POST request via SOCKS proxy (aka TOR) multiple times while I change IP each time I "post" stuff. Many things I tried did fail:

- `requesocks` seems to be broken
- I have to edit TOR files to use `requests[socks]` module but the file that I gotta change is not even similar to the one in TOR's own website.

The psuedo code that I used and worked (at least for once with a VPN) and returned me a response: (doesn't include proxies)

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
response = session.get("some website")
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}
payload = {
    "var1": "data1",
    "var2": "data2"
}
response = session.post("some other website", headers=headers, data=payload)

print response.text
```

I hope it's clear enough, some help would save me a whole month. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the Python code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656877/trying-to-automate-tor-to-do-something-on-a-site-and-change-identity-each-time) will help you.  The above code doesn't have any proxy handling, and in order to change your IP after each request, you need to connect to Tor's controller and instruct it to change identities.